# How to debug an EnvoyFilter in Istio?

Tags: debugging, istio, envoyproxy

I have the filter below.

I am checking the logs for the gateway and it does *not* look like the filter is applied.

1. How do I debug an `EnvoyFilter`?
2. Where can I see which filters are applied on *each* request?

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: proper-filter-name-here
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.lua
          typed_config:
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
            inlineCode: |
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                 request_handle:logDebug("Hello World!")
              end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic is very well described in [the documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/):

> The simplest kind of Istio logging is [Envoy’s access logging](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log/usage). Envoy proxies print access information to their standard output. The standard output of Envoy’s containers can then be printed by the `kubectl logs` command.

You have asked:

> Where can I see what filters are applied each request?

Based on [this issue on github](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/11129):

> There is no generic mechanism.

It follows that if you wanted to see what filter was applied to each request, you would have to create your custom solution.

However, without any problem, you can get logs about each request based on [this fragment in the documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#enable-envoy-s-access-logging):

> If you used an  `IstioOperator`  CR to install Istio, add the following field to your configuration:

```yaml
spec:
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
```

> Otherwise, add the equivalent setting to your original  `istioctl install`  command, for example:

```
istioctl  install  <flags-you-used-to-install-Istio> --set meshConfig.accessLogFile=/dev/stdout
```

> You can also choose between JSON and text by setting  `accessLogEncoding`  to  `JSON`  or  `TEXT`.
> You may also want to customize the  [format](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log/usage#format-rules)  of the access log by editing  `accessLogFormat`.
>
> Refer to  [global mesh options](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/#MeshConfig)  for more information on all three of these settings:

- `meshConfig.accessLogFile`
- `meshConfig.accessLogEncoding`
- `meshConfig.accessLogFormat`

You can also [change access log format](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#default-access-log-format) and [test the access log](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#test-the-access-log) from linked instructions.

See also (EDIT):

- [How to debug your Istio networking configuration](https://www.tetrate.io/blog/debugging-your-istio-networking-configuration/):

> - EnvoyFilters will manifest where you tell Istio to put them. Typically a bad EnvoyFilter will manifest as Envoy rejecting the configuration (i.e. not being in the SYNCED state above) and you need to check Istiod (Pilot) logs for the errors from Envoy rejecting the configuration.

> - If configuration didn’t appear in Envoy at all– Envoy did not ACK it, or it’s an EnvoyFilter configuration– it’s likely that the configuration is invalid (Istio cannot syntactically validate the configuration inside of an EnvoyFilter) or is located in the wrong spot in Envoy’s configuration.

- [Debugging Envoy and Istiod](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/)
- [Using EnvoyFilters to Debug Requests](https://karlstoney.com/2021/07/07/using-envoyfilters-to-debug/)

Comment: Thank you. I am tailing the log from my istio-ingressgateway, but I cannot seem to find out why the filter I added is not used.

Comment: @2240, I have edited the answer and added more info about debugging envoy. First and second link should be most useful.